# Scala Extractor unapply called twice

Tags: scala, case, collect, extractor

I just discovered that unapply in my extractor is being called twice for some reason.
Anyone know why, and how to avoid it?

```
val data = List("a","b","c","d","e")

object Uap {
  def unapply( s:String ) = {
    println("S: "+s)
    Some(s+"!")
  }             
}

println( data.collect{ case Uap(x) => x } )
```

This produces output:

```
S: a
S: a
S: b
S: b
S: c
S: c
S: d
S: d
S: e
S: e
List(a!, b!, c!, d!, e!)
```

The final result is fine but in my real program the unapply is non-trivial, so I certainly don't want to call it twice!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

collect takes a `PartialFunction` as input.  `PartialFunction` defines two key members: `isDefinedAt` and `apply`.  When collect runs your function, it runs your extractor once to determine if your function `isDefinedAt` some particular input, and if it is, then it runs the extractor again as part of `apply` to extract the value.

If there is a trivial way of correctly implementing isDefinedAt, you could implement this yourself by implementing your own PartialFunction explicitly, instead of using the case syntax. or you could do a `filter` and then `map` with a total function on the collection (which is essentially what collect is doing by calling `isDefinedAt`, then `apply`)

Another option would be to `lift` the Partial function to a total function.  `PartialFunction` defines `lift` which turns a `PartialFunction[A,B]` into a `A=>Option[B]`.  You could use this lifted function (call it `fun`) to do: `data.map(fun).collect { case Some(x) => x }`

Comment: Another option is to cache the last value in the partial function object.

Comment: @Greg This is true, but kind of Old School, in that it is an implementation detail that is not true in 2.11, and has a somewhat ok fix in 2.10.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, this was addressed in 2.11 as a performance bug:

```
$ skala
Welcome to Scala version 2.11.0-20130423-194141-5ec9dbd6a9 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_06).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> val data = List("a","b","c","d","e")
data: List[String] = List(a, b, c, d, e)

scala> 

scala> object Uap {
     |   def unapply( s:String ) = {
     |     println("S: "+s)
     |     Some(s+"!")
     |   }             
     | }
defined object Uap

scala> 

scala> println( data.collect{ case Uap(x) => x } )
S: a
S: b
S: c
S: d
S: e
List(a!, b!, c!, d!, e!)
```

See the efficiency notes on [applyOrElse](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.PartialFunction).

Here's a version for 2.10, where the issue is easily remedied by extension:

```
object Test extends App {
  import scala.collection.TraversableLike
  import scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom
  import scala.collection.immutable.StringLike

  implicit class Collector[A, Repr, C <: TraversableLike[A, Repr]](val c: C) extends AnyVal {
    def collecting[B, That](pf: PartialFunction[A, B])(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[Repr, B, That]): That = {
      val b = bf(c.repr)
      c.foreach(pf.runWith(b += _))
      b.result
    }
  }

  val data = List("a","b","c","d","e")

  object Uap {
    def unapply( s:String ) = {
      println("S: "+s)
      s match {
        case "foo" => None
        case _     => Some(s+"!")
      }
    }
  }
  val c = Collector[String, List[String], List[String]](data)
  Console println c.collecting { case Uap(x) => x }
}
```

Result:

```
$ scalac -version
Scala compiler version 2.10.1 -- Copyright 2002-2013, LAMP/EPFL

apm@halyard ~/tmp
$ scalac applyorelse.scala ; scala applyorelse.Test
S: a
S: b
S: c
S: d
S: e
List(a!, b!, c!, d!, e!)
```

Note that this version of Uap is partial:

```
scala> val data = List("a","b","c","d","e", "foo")
data: List[String] = List(a, b, c, d, e, foo)

scala> data.map{ case Uap(x) => x }
S: a
S: b
S: c
S: d
S: e
S: foo
scala.MatchError: foo (of class java.lang.String)
```

I think that if the use case is PF, the code should be partial.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @stew answer, `collect` is implemented as:

```
def collect[B, That](pf: PartialFunction[A, B])(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[Repr, B, That]): That = {
val b = bf(repr)
for (x <- this) if (pf.isDefinedAt(x)) b += pf(x)
b.result
}
```

It uses `pf.isDefinedAt(x)`. Doing `scalac -Xprint:typer check.scala` (`check.scala` contains your code). It prints:

```
....
final def isDefinedAt(x1: String): Boolean = ((x1.asInstanceOf[String]:String): String @unchecked) match {
      case check.this.Uap.unapply(<unapply-selector>) <unapply> ((x @ _)) => true
      case (defaultCase$ @ _) => false
    }
```

So as you see, it calls `unapply` here again. This explains why it prints twice i.e. once to check if it is defined and then next when it is already called in `pf(x).

@som-snytt is right. As of Scala 2.11, collect function in `TraversableLike` is changed to:

```
def collect[B, That](pf: PartialFunction[A, B])(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[Repr, B, That]): That = {
val b = bf(repr)
foreach(pf.runWith(b += _))
b.result
}
```

The reason it prints only once is that, internally it calls `applyOrElse` which checks if  it is defined. If yes applies the function there it self (in above case `(b += _)`). Hence it prints only once.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `map` instead:

```
scala>    println( data.map{ case Uap(x) => x } )
S: a
S: b
S: c
S: d
S: e
List(a!, b!, c!, d!, e!)
```

No idea why it works that why.

Comment: Don't think I can.  In my real application I'm actually doing selection logic in the unapply so it doesn't always return Some(something).  Map always needs a 1-for-1 result.

Comment: Since the OP pattern match is not partial, I think it's not fair to down-vote. Use cases matter.